# PHP page hit counters in database

Tags: php, mysqli, analytics, hitcounter

I run a podcast network and I'm redoing my site from scratch.  One of the features on my network is to listen to podcasts directly from the site in an HTML5 player. I have all that functionality working just fine, but I'd like some analytical data on those pages.

I'd like to make a hit counter in PHP and store it in a DB table. But, there's only one page. The player loads each show, dependent on the query string, then it pulls the latest episode from their RSS Feed, like so: http://tangentboundnetwork.com/new/show.php?id=1

I want to be able to put analytical data into a table and use it for the hosts of whatever show(s) are on the network.

I just need to know where to start.  Any ideas, Links, and examples would be welcome.

Comment: What is the `id` in the adress? Is it the ID of the show being listened to? If not, what is it?

Comment: How about this.. similar to what you need: http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/Tracking-Website-Statistics-with-PHP/

Comment: @Anders - that is the id of the show.

Comment: @Jordan - I don't know if I need all that data, basically, I just need a quick hit counter.  Though, that might be something I could use for the rest of the site - I'm kind of digging that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, create your database table `VISITOR_COUNT`. You will need at least two columns - `SHOW_ID` and `COUNT`.

The code in `show.php` could look something like this:

- If you want to count unique (or sort of unique - you can never be completely sure) visitors, check if a specific cookie for the current `$id` is set. Read more about cookies in PHP [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp).
- If the cookie is not set:

  - Set the cookie.
  - Check if there is a row in `VISITOR_COUNT` with `SHOW_ID = :id` where `:id` is the value of `$id`. Watch out for [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)!
  - If there is, run some SQL to update it: `UPDATE VISITOR_COUNT SET COUNT = COUNT + 1 WHERE SHOW_ID = :id`
  - If not, insert a row with the right ID and a count value of 1.